# ModuleNotFoundError huggingface datasets in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-datasets

I want to use the huggingface datasets library from within a Jupyter notebook.

This should be as simple as installing it (`pip install datasets`, in bash within a venv) and importing it (`import datasets`, in Python or notebook).

All works well when I test it in the standard Python interactive shell, however, when trying in a Jupyter notebook, it says:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-652e886d387f> in <module>
----> 1 import datasets

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'datasets'
```

At first, I thought it might be the case that the notebook kernel uses a different virtual environment, but I verified from within the notebook that the package is installed:

`!pip install datasets`

```
Requirement already satisfied: datasets in /home/yoga/venvs/text_embeddings/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.17 in /home/yoga/venvs/text_embeddings/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from datasets) (1.21.0)
Requirement already satisfied: xxhash in /home/yoga/venvs/text_embeddings/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from datasets) (2.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pyarrow<4.0.0,>=1.0.0 in /home/yoga/venvs/text_embeddings/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from datasets) (3.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /home/yoga/venvs/text_embeddings/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from datasets) (1.2.5)
Requirement already satisfied: fsspec in /home/yoga/venvs/text_embeddings/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from datasets) (2021.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in /home/yoga/venvs/text_embeddings/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from datasets) (20.9)
Requirement already satisfied: dill in /home/yoga/venvs/text_embeddings/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from datasets) (0.3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.19.0 in /home/yoga/venvs/text_embeddings/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from datasets) (2.25.1)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm<4.50.0,>=4.27 in /home/yoga/venvs/text_embeddings/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from datasets) (4.49.0)
Requirement already satisfied: multiprocess in /home/yoga/venvs/text_embeddings/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from datasets) (0.70.12.2)
Requirement already satisfied: huggingface-hub<0.1.0 in /home/yoga/venvs/text_embeddings/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from datasets) (0.0.13)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.3 in /home/yoga/venvs/text_embeddings/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pandas->datasets) (2021.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7.3 in /home/yoga/venvs/text_embeddings/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pandas->datasets) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.0.2 in /home/yoga/venvs/text_embeddings/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from packaging->datasets) (2.4.7)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /home/yoga/venvs/text_embeddings/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from requests>=2.19.0->datasets) (2021.5.30)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<5,>=3.0.2 in /home/yoga/venvs/text_embeddings/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from requests>=2.19.0->datasets) (4.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in /home/yoga/venvs/text_embeddings/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from requests>=2.19.0->datasets) (1.26.6)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in /home/yoga/venvs/text_embeddings/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from requests>=2.19.0->datasets) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions in /home/yoga/venvs/text_embeddings/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from huggingface-hub<0.1.0->datasets) (3.10.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: filelock in /home/yoga/venvs/text_embeddings/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from huggingface-hub<0.1.0->datasets) (3.0.12)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /home/yoga/venvs/text_embeddings/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7.3->pandas->datasets) (1.16.0)
```

and

`!pip freeze`

```
certifi==2021.5.30
chardet==4.0.0
datasets==1.8.0
dill==0.3.4
filelock==3.0.12
fsspec==2021.6.1
huggingface-hub==0.0.13
idna==2.10
multiprocess==0.70.12.2
numpy==1.21.0
packaging==20.9
pandas==1.2.5
pyarrow==3.0.0
pyparsing==2.4.7
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2021.1
requests==2.25.1
six==1.16.0
tqdm==4.49.0
typing-extensions==3.10.0.0
urllib3==1.26.6
xxhash==2.0.2
```

Any ideas? Do I need to configure the notebook in a special way, or is there a problem with the datasets module? Thanks!

---

**Edit:** Following the answer below, this makes the error go away:

```
datasets_dir=r"/home/yoga/venvs/text_embeddings/lib/python3.8/site-packages/datasets"

import sys
sys.path.append(datasets_dir)

import datasets
```

But is there a way that works without setting this path explicitely? (Or can somebody explain why this is necessary here?)

Comment: I just tested in a virtual env and cannot replicate the issue. What is the fulltraceback?

Comment: Thanks! I updated the question with the full traceback. As I've written, the issue only occurs within the notebook, not within the interactive shell.

Comment: Try creating a new env using conda: `conda create -n py39_test_env python=3.9` then activate `conda activate py39_test_env` then install `pip install datasets` then launch jupyter `jupyter notebook`

Comment: Thanks - forgot to say, I am using standard python not conda. Will it only work with conda?

Comment: Creating a new environment worked for me. I tried the given solution it didn't replicate well in my case. Anyways, Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had faced similar problem but with another library, this worked for me

`import sys`
`sys.path.append(r"path to datasets in python env")`
`import dataset_utils`

Path in your case -> "/home/yoga/venvs/text_embeddings/lib/python3.8/site-packages/datasets"

My guess is that the environment variable does not has the `PYTHONPATH` is not set up correctly. **PYTHONPATH** is an environment variable those content is added to the sys.path where Python looks for modules. You can set it to whatever you like

This should work!!

Comment: This works! Can you explain what is happening there? I hardly can believe that this is the recommended way of using the datasets package...

Comment: My guess is that the environment variable does not has the PYTHONPATH is not set up correctly.

PYTHONPATH is an environment variable those content is added to the sys.path where Python looks for modules. You can set it to whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

I installed datasets via Jupyter Notebook with the command:
!pip install datasets